Splitting a large expression for parallel evaluation
I have a huge expression which I need to expand around $x\to0$. In sequential evaluation, it takes huge time. So, I was thinking to partition it into the number of kernels and evaluate paralleled and then finally add up to get the total result.
My expression contains not only polynomials, but some special functions also. For example
expr=1 + x + x^2 + H[0, 1, x] + H[0, 1, x] H[0, 2]/x + j[C1, 1, 0, 1]

I tried using Length command to get the number of terms, then Ceilling[Length/kernel] to get terms in each partition. But unfortunately, it misses terms when Length=7, kernel=3 , then first two should contain 3,3, and the last should contain 1 term. How to achieve this?
My try
parts = Partition[terms, Ceiling[Length[terms]/numKernels]];
Print[parts];
results = ParallelMap[Series[Total[#], {x, 0, n}] &, parts];
finalResult = Total[results];


I think Parallelization doesn't help much. If I were you, I first expand the functions H[ ] and j[ ] and then use the result to obtain the expansion of "expr".

As @A.Kato suggests, I think I would be looking for common subexpressions (e.g. your example has H[0,1,x] twice).  Evaluating each of these only could easily give a substantial saving.

expr = 1 + x + x^2 + H[0, 1, x] + H[0, 1, x] H[0, 2]/x + 
   j[C1, 1, 0, 1];

ParallelMap[Normal[Series[#, {x, 0, 1}]] &, expr]


??

Yes, the mapper will map over Plus just as happily as it maps over List, and so there is no need to make your expression into a List. With Method -> "FinestGrained" it might work even a bit better (to be tried out).
